# Trying to fit two columns next to eachother, but overlapping when shrink the view port

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a profile page for a site I am currently working on. When viewing this in a desktop (anything above a tablet) I need it to show two cards next to each other, but there is a minimum width set due to the buttons in the card moving out of place when shrunk.

I have some empty column's on each side to pad the page out.

So I have made it so when you are in a large desktop, it pads the page out and the two cards are next to one another which is perfect.

But when I get less than 1175px, the two cards start to overlap each other, instead of this happening, I want the right card to jump right below the left card which has the profile information in it.

I have made it so it doesn't show up in mobile too, but I also want it to show with the two column's one underneath the other for mobile too.

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="container-fluid pcontainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2 d-none d-lg-block">
    test
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="card pc mw-100">
          <div class="card-title">
          <img class="pp card-img-top img-fluid rounded-circle" src="img/pp.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="pt card-title text-left text-justify"> Ryan Edwards </h4>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btnp btn-outline-info">Add Friend</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Message</button>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3> My Biography: </h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="card pc mw-100">
          <div class="card-title">
          <img class="pp card-img-top img-fluid rounded-circle" src="img/pp.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
          <h4 class="pt card-title text-left text-justify"> Ryan Edwards </h4>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btnp btn-outline-info">Add Friend</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success">Message</button>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <h3> My Biography: </h3>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2 d-none d-lg-block">
    test
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the css:

```
.pc {
margin: 0px;
min-width:390px;       
width: auto !important;  
width:390px;            

}

.pp {
max-width: 125px;
width: 125px;
max-height: 125px;
height: 125px;
margin-top: 40px;
margin-right: 40px;
float: right;

}

.pt {
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
}

.btnp {
margin-left: 50px;
}

.btn {
padding-top: 2px;
padding-bottom: 2px;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use a script tag?
You can set the distance and add a new class for your current one. Not sure if its going to help you :)

```
$(document).ready(() => {
        $(document).scroll(() => {
            if ($('.yourclass').offset().top - $(window).scrollTop() <= 25) {

                if ($(window).scrollTop() < 400) {
                    $('.yourclass').removeClass('currentyclass');
                } else {
                    $('.yourclass').addClass('newestclass');

                }
            }


        })
```

Comment: im not sure what a script tag is but will have a go, im new and learning. ill do some research and have a look